# Extract from a database

Tags: python, sql

I have a database that I need to extract from. The database has the following tables:

Shops
YELP business listing, with name, phone number etc.
Also has locationid

Locations
Contains Name (London, New York), locationID, parentid
ParentID allows the table to be in a hierarchy.

Eg. There might be a location New York State and New York City
In this case NYC's parentid would be the New York state object.

Categories
 Categories have an id and name
eg. Car dealer, Boat dealer)

ShopCategories
Each business has multiple BusinessCategories
Contains businessid and categoriesid.

We then serve a large number of search result pages based on location and business category.

eg.

New York City All Business Categories
New York City Boat Dealers
New York City Car Dealers
New York State All Business Categories
New York State Boat Dealers
New York State Car Dealers

Note: Search results will show businesses in that location and any child locations.
Example: New York State would show businesses listed in NYC.

I need to write a python script that will allow me to know if 2 search result pages are listing the same businesses.

Example: If all the boat dealers in New York State existed within NYC then both pages:

New York State Boat Dealers
New York City Boat Dealers

Would list the same businesses.

I need some general advise of how to tackle efficiently

```
mysql> DESC categories;
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field        | Type             | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |   
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| CategoryID   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |   
| CategoryName | char(50)         | NO   |     |                   |                             |   
| timestamp    | timestamp        | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.07 sec)

mysql> DESC shopcategories;
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field          | Type             | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |   
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| ShopCategoryID | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |   
| ShopID         | int(10) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                             |   
| CategoryID     | int(10) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                             |   
| timestamp      | timestamp        | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DESC locations;
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field           | Type             | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |   
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| LocationID      | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |   
| LocationName    | char(50)         | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |   
| LocationUrlName | varchar(100)     | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |   
| ParentID        | int(10) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |   
| timestamp       | timestamp        | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
| postcode        | char(5)          | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |   
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
mysql> 
mysql> desc shops;
+---------------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field               | Type             | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |   
+---------------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| ShopID              | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |   
| ContactAddressID    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | 0                 |                             |   
| OwnerID             | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | 0                 |                             |   
| ShopName            | int(10) unsigned    | Null  | MUL | 109              |                             |   
| LocationID           | varchar(50)      | NO   |     |                   |                             |   
| ShopUrlName         | varchar(300)     | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |                |                             |
```

Comment: Have you solved your problem eventually?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use `oursql` module. It's very simple and pretty powerful.

Here is the tutorial: https://pythonhosted.org/oursql/index.html

---

## Basic steps

#### Connect to DB

```
conn = oursql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', user='habnabit', passwd='foobar',
    db='example', port=3307)
```

#### Create cursor and execute query

```
curs = conn.cursor(oursql.DictCursor)
curs.execute(
    'SELECT * FROM `some_table` WHERE `col1` = ? AND `col2` = ?',
    (42, -3))
```

#### Get results

```
curs.fetchall()
```

All those examples are taken from the tutorial. If you wanted to read more about those classes and their methods, here is the API reference:
https://pythonhosted.org/oursql/api.html#

---

And for your comparison... I'd simply compare IDs of results.